# Invoking a web service in a Web API Project…in which layer to invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-web-api, web-api

I am using **Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2** and one of my end points has to internally invoke a legacy non-Microsoft web service (not `asmx` or `svc`) .

Which layer should I invoke this in?

I currently have :
**Repository layer:** where all the CRUD calls to DB are done now.

**Domain Manager:** where respective manager classes invoke the `Repository Layer` methods.

And my **Web API Controller** methods invoke the respective Domain Manager methods.

Should I just have another method in my **Repository Layer** which invokes the web service? And follow the usual pattern above?

Answer (score 1):

The repository layer is the logical place to put it; the data that you're pulling back from the web service will need to be wrapped in domain-specific abstractions, so (in concept) it is essentially another data store alongside your own databases.